# Will the price change on Airbnb if I provide my ID later?

Tags: bookings, hotels, airbnb

Recently I booked an apartment on Airbnb and I paid the full amount of money. Then Airbnb asked me to provide some legal documents like ID to finish the procedure of booking, would the booking price change if I submit my ID like 2 weeks later?

Comment: Are you sure it let you confirm the booking? I had to upload my ID before it let me complete my first booking, and as a host, I've never received a booking where the guest didn't have their ID already added, even if they were a new user with no other info.

Comment: I take it back, I just looked and I do have a future confirmed booking from someone with no ID uploaded. Weird. (Posting a follow-up comment instead of deleting the previous one in case anyone else has the same question I did.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends, if you have already paid like you have stated, and the booking has been *confirmed*, the price should not change according to Airbnb's reply on twitter. But, the host could cancel your booking if you ignore their request to send ID for weeks. If you message them and explain why you can't provide it straight away they could be fine with that.

Whereas if the actual booking has not yet been confirmed and is awaiting the ID before doing so, it is as if you haven't pressed the book button at all, the process is not complete so the money won't leave your account, and anyone else could book it in the meantime. This means that the price could change, or the home could be taken by the time 2 weeks is up.

The reply I got from Airbnb:

> Hi Ucie, if the reservation is already confirmed, the price should not
>   change. Can you please send us your email address, so we can identify
>   your account and check. We’ll follow up from there.

If you message them at @airbnbhelp they should be able to confirm 100% what case your booking falls under, and they will be the only ones who can say for certain what will happen.

Comment: Hosts cannot cancel confirmed bookings without substantial penalties. I'm not sure what will happen if the guest doesn't upload their ID before their booked stay starts.

Answer (score 9):

You should contact AirBnB support directly; make it clear to them and the host that you will add your valid ID (passport, drivers license...) by such and such date.

I would assume (expect?) that if by that time you have not entered your ID, the reservation will be canceled and your money will be refunded (**don't quote me, go to AirBnB support**)

From AirBnB:

"[If you need to come back and finish adding your ID later](https://www.airbnb.ca/help/article/1237/how-does-it-work-when-airbnb-asks-for-an-id), that’s fine. Just go to airbnb.com/verify and you can pick up where you left off."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the price could change. By how much it will change, no-one will know. After all, it could be sold already. The booking isn’t complete until the ID is verified and until the booking isn’t complete the price could always change.

Comment: The OP allready paid.